# Sort then split a PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays, split, hashmap, asymptotic-complexity

Here is a `var_dump` of my array:

```
array(6) {
    [0]=> string(4) "quack"
    ["DOG"]=> string(4) "quack"
    [1]=> string(4) "quack"
    ["CAT"]=> string(4) "quack"
    [2]=> string(4) "Aaaaarrrrrggggghhhhh"
    ["CAERBANNOG"]=> string(4) "Aaaaarrrrrggggghhhhh"
}
```

*(just for fun I've included two puns in this code, try and find them!)*

#### How do I split this array into two arrays, one containing all the `quack`s; the other `Aaaaarrrrrggggghhhhh`?

---

Note that it won't always be in consecutive order, so was thinking maybe nested hashmaps, something like:

1. Check `if (isset($myarr['$found_val']))`
2. Append that array if found
3. Else create that place with a new array

But not sure how the arrays are implemented, so could be O(n) to append, in which case I'd need some other solution...

Answer (score 1):

You can just group them based on values and store the keys

```
$array = array(0 => "quack","DOG" => "quack",1 => "quack","CAT" => "quack",2 => "Aaaaarrrrrggggghhhhh","CAERBANNOG" => "Aaaaarrrrrggggghhhhh");

$final = array();
foreach ( $array as $key => $value ) {
    if (! array_key_exists($value, $final)) {
        $final[$value] = array();
    }
    $final[$value][] = $key;
}

var_dump($final);
```

Output

```
array
  'quack' => 
    array
      0 => int 0
      1 => string 'DOG' (length=3)
      2 => int 1
      3 => string 'CAT' (length=3)
  'Aaaaarrrrrggggghhhhh' => 
    array
      0 => int 2
      1 => string 'CAERBANNOG' (length=10)
```

Comment: +1 beat me to it :) however I'd do `$final[$value]=array($key);` to be slightly shorter - in place of the else. ps. you have two var_dumps :)

Comment: @pebbl sorry about that ... :)

Comment: I would rewrite that either way. To prevent doing this `$final[$value][] = $key;` multiple times in the code. Just create the element if array key does not exist and always just append it.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone wants to do this in a more of and odd way:

**Updated** with air4x's idea of using only a single item array, instead of `array_fill(0,count($a),$v)`. Makes it's much more sensible.

```
$a = array(
  0 => "quack",
  "DOG" => "quack",
  1 => "quack",
  "CAT" => "quack",
  2 => "Aaaaarrrrrggggghhhhh",
  "CAERBANNOG" => "Aaaaarrrrrggggghhhhh"
);

$b = array();
foreach( array_unique(array_values($a)) as $v ) {
  $b[$v] = array_intersect($a, array($v));
}

echo '<xmp>';
print_r($b);
```

Totally not optimal - *difficult to read* - but still interesting :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$quacks_arr = array_intersect($your_array, array('quack'));
$argh_arr   = array_intersect($your_array, array('Aaaaarrrrrggggghhhhh'));
```

If you want to sort them, then just do ksort

```
ksort($quacks_arr);
ksort($argh_arr);
```

Comment: +1 I had not realised that I could use just a one item array for `array_intersect`. I'd falsely assumed it would compare against every key offset. nice.